# How to get linux onto old IBM thinkpad?

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I have an IBM thinkpad 760LD which only has a floppy drive, a serial port, and a parallel port to communicate with. I would like to install minimal ubuntu on to the computer. I don't have another computer that can burn floppy disks. Is it possible to send data through the serial port to the hard drive? I also have a pcmcia ethernet/modem card installed if that helps.

Comment: [That machine](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:760LD), being very old, probably won't run a modern Ubuntu. But you could find an USB floppy drive and use an older distros.

Comment: Back in the day, floppies were "written to", not "burned" :-)

Comment: Opening the back of the laptop would enable you to extract the hard drive, which you could attach to another computer and write the distribution there. Running anything modern and graphical on a machine with 8MB ram and a 640x480 display is going to be a frustrating exercise. firefox and chrome can use over 100 times as much memory as you have. A raspberry pi 4 will be about 100 times faster than this laptop.

Comment: @icarus this probably has an IDE drive, not SATA.   IDE interfaces are pretty rare on modern motherboards (although it's not hard to find USB IDE adaptors).

Comment: @person this machine's specs say it has 8-64 MB (not GB, MB) of RAM.  I doubt if you can find any current (or even near-current) linux distro that will run in 8MB.   64MB, perhaps.  But an ancient distro from the mid-late 90s would be OK (my first linux box was an amd 386-40 with 4MB...took all night to compile the kernel).

Comment: your best option, though, is to look for something a bit newer - something with at least a few GB of RAM, sata drive, and the ability to boot from either a USB stick or a CD-ROM or over the network with pxe.   it might be hard to find but should be free or very inexpensive (laptops are considered "disposable" by most consumers, they want the new shiny).

Comment: You will need something very lightweigt, distro-wise.  Maybe http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/index.html or http://puppylinux.com/

Comment: There is an informative German wiki page: [thinkwiki.de/760](https://thinkwiki.de/760) ([google translated](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fthinkwiki.de%2F760)). 
It lists usable Linux distros, infos on how to boot from CD-ROM, how to exchange data between Thinkpad and PC...

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an operating system on that computer, then you can likely use it to receive a file over the serial port. You'd use a modem comm program to receive it via, e.g., Z-Modem protocol. Otherwise, PC BIOSes didn't typically have any feature to load software via serial port.

You'll also need a Linux distro that can install via floppy. There aren't many (any?) of those left, though you could use an old version. Debian, for example, I think last supported this in Etch. Not sure about Ubuntu.

@icarus points out you have Ethernet. That'd be a good way to get data to the machine and much faster than a null modem cable. I have no idea if it can netboot, but if so that'd avoid needing floppies.

Also, I hope you're doing this just to see if it can be done. I doubt it'll actually be useful for anything.

Comment: Using the ethernet the OP says he has would be much faster than using the serial port. Agree about needing a distro that can install via floppy. The OP has the added joy that they may need to repartition the disk that holds the OS.

Comment: The laptop has 40 MB of ram. I believe the hard drive is dead because windows says there is an “I/O” error with the drive (I have an ide to USB converter). Unfortunately IBM has proprietary devices and I can’t replace the hard drive with a non IBM hard drive. I’ll have to find a way to write to a floppy disk.

Comment: @person so your plan is to run linux off a single floppy disk (Perhaps 1.4Mb) and 40 MB ram, no hard drive at all? Using this diskless with the OS provided over the network if you have another machine would seem the way to go. If the machine can netboot from the BIOS that would be the correct thing to do, Otherwise get a floppy disk image from say http://etherboot.org